# How to minimize max value in Google OR-Tools?

Tags: optimization, or-tools

I am developing a model to solve a MILP problem using Google OR-Tools and Python. I have a problem with **t** tasks. Every task **i** needs **w_i** weeks to be completed and **p_i_t** workers on that specific week. There is a total time in weeks to complete all tasks. I need to optimize (min) the max value of workers needed in a particular week (variables to define: starting week for every particular task, or similar).

There is also a constraint: once a task starts, it should be finished. All tasks could run in parallel if needed.

Is it possible to model this problem using Google OR-Tools?. I have been trying to add a max Python function inside solver.Minimize but it is not working. How do I implement it correctly in Google OR tools?

Comment: You could create a new variable `obj` constraint that the number of workers is smaller than that variable and minimize it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably it was not clear on my question, the **w_i** weeks needed to complete each task and the **p_i_t** workers are given (fixed data/information). The variables to be defined are the week in which each task start.

Comment: Is there a constraint on the number of workers available? Otherwise you can just start all tasks at the same time and sum up the number of workers needed every week.

Comment: No, there is no limit on the number of workers. If you start all tasks at the same time you are not going to get the best solution.